# What causes a vehicle to idle so low that it stalls?

Tags: mazda, stall, rough-idle, tribute

My 2003 Mazda tribute is idling extremely low and shuts it self off when stopped for longer than a 30-45 seconds. There is no check engine or anything but I ran a I/M test and it showed these problems:

Cat -> X

EVAP -> X

O2S -> X

HRT -> X

EGR -> X

What could be the possible issues?

Comment: Biggest cause is the throttle body is dirty and need a good cleaning.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Can you keep the vehicle running if you modulate the throttle? Also, clear the codes and run it again. Those codes, if active, should be throwing a check engine light. Also ensure  your CEL is working properly. You should be able to see it come on during a key on, then go out. This is the system's power on diagnostics.

Comment: It turned out to be the throttle body. Thanks Moab!